# Insert new calendar event and set minutes for default reminder using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

Is it possible to set reminder (change default minutes of default reminder which is "10 minutes, notification") using Intent?

This is how I create Intent, but I have no idea how to set reminder here or change default minutes of default reminder

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT).apply {
    data = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI
    putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, ...
    putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, ...
    putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, ...
}
```

Is it possible with Intent and putExtra?

[image]